# Estimate the derivative with Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose a metric $d$ is defined on the space of entire functions as follows:

$$d(f, g)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \min \left\{\frac{1}{2^{n}}, \max _{|z| \leq n}|f(z)-g(z)|\right\}$$
Is the operator of differentiation (the operator sending $f$ to $f^\prime$)  continuous on this metric space of functions? Explain why or why not.

Here is my try with Cauchy's Integral Formula.
 For $|z|<n$,
$$\begin{aligned}|f^\prime(z)-g^\prime(z)|&=
|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w|=n}\frac{f(w)-g(w)}{(w-z)^2} dw|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \max_{|w|\leq n}|f(w)-g(w)| \int_{|w|=n} \frac{1}{(w-z)^2} dw.
 \end{aligned}$$

Since $z$ can be very closed to the boundary, $|w-z|$ can be very small. I don't know how to bound the integral in the inequality.

Any idea to solve this question?

Comment: So, if attempting to prove that differentiation is continuous is running into difficulty, have you tried the opposite, proving that it is not continuous? In, particular, guided by what has gone wrong with your attempt to prove that it is?

Comment: it might help to note that this metric exactly gives the topology of pointwise convergence

Comment: @LukasRollier: No, this is a metric which gives locally uniform convergence.

Comment: Hint: You can bound $|f'(z)-g'(z)|$ for $|z| \le n$ in terms of the bound of $|f(z)-g(z)|$ for $|z| \le 2n$.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience I will use the notation $M_n = \max\limits_{|z|=n} |f(z)-g(z)|$ and $M_n' = \max\limits_{|z|=n} |f'(z)-g'(z)|$. The trick is to integrate over a larger circle. I.e., for $|z| \le n$ you have
$$
\begin{split}
|f'(z)-g'(z)| &= \left| \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=2n} \frac{f(w)-g(w)}{(w-z)^2} \, dw \right| \le \frac{M_{2n}}{2\pi} \int_{|w|=2n} \frac{|dw|}{|w-z|^2} \\
& \le \frac{M_{2n}}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{4\pi n}{n^2}
= \frac{2M_{2n}}n \le 2 M_{2n}.
\end{split}
$$
Now if $d(f,g) < 2^{-2N}$ for some positive integer $N$, then by the definition of $d$ we have $M_{2n} < 2^{-2N}$ as long as $n \le N$, which implies that $|f'(z)-g'(z)| \le 2^{-2N+1}$ for $1 \le n \le N$, and so $M_{n}' \le 2^{-2N+1}$ for $1 \le n \le N$. This shows that
$$
d(f',g') \le \sum_{n=1}^N M_n' + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \le N 2^{-2N+1} + 2^{-N}
$$
and since this goes to $0$ as $N \to \infty$, it shows that $f \mapsto f'$ is continuous with respect to this metric.